# Как выровнять ссылку по центру ячейки таблицы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не выравнивается ссылка по центру ячейки таблицы. Пробовал добавлять `display:inline-block`, `text-align:center`, `vertical-align: middle`. Пробовал через `flex`.

Так с таблицей вообще непонятно что происходит, подскажите как решить проблему? Код прилагается.

PS в редакторе `stackowerflow` почему-то все нормально вроде, а локально кнопка прилипает к левому верхнему краю.

```css
@import "reset.css";


html{
    font-size: 0.625em;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border: 29px solid hsl(219, 27%, 31%);
    }

    .border-right {
        border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 81%);;
        }
    .background-light{
        background: #F2F2F2;
    }
    .background-grey{
        background: #E3E3E3;
    }
    .left-column{
        width: 31.3rem;
    }
    .header{
        height: 15.9rem;
    }
    .basic-columns{
        width: 28rem;
        height: 7.2rem;

    }
    .button-columns{
        width: 28rem;
        height: 12rem;

    }

     .td-basic{
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        width: 28rem;
        height: 7.2rem;
        font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        color: hsl(0, 0%, 28%);
    } 

    .icons{
        margin-right: 1rem;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        color: hsl(0, 0%, 52%);
    }
      /* .flex-button{
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }    */
    .button{
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        color: #fff;
        /* line-height: 2.8rem; */
        padding: 1.3rem 4.6rem 0.9rem 4.6rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.3rem #ccc;
    }

    .dark-btn{
        background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 28%);
        border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
    }

    .green-btn{
        background-color: hsl(84, 60%, 48%);
        border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(84, 64%, 42%);
    }

    .red-btn{
        background-color: hsl(356, 85%, 62%);
        border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(356, 72%, 55%);
    }

    .blue-btn{
        background-color: hsl(178, 60%, 31%);
        border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(177, 68%, 27%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Prising Table</title>
</head>
<body>
  
    <table>
        <!-- <caption>Test table for PE</caption> -->
        <colgroup>
            <col span="2" class="own-items">
            <col class="another-items">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="left-column header border-right">Заголовок 1</th>
            <th class="basic-columns header border-right">Standart</th>
            <th class="basic-columns header border-right">Ultimate</th>
            <th class="basic-columns header">Premium</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td class="flex-button left-column border-right"><a href="#void" class="button dark-btn">Contact Us</a></td>
            <td class="button-columns border-right"><a href="#void" class="button green-btn">Buy now</a></td>
            <td class="button-columns border-right"><a href="#void" class="button red-btn">Buy now</a></td>
            <td class="button-columns"><a href="#void" class="button blue-btn">Buy now</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="background-light">
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right" ><i class="fas fa-archive icons"></i>Storage</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right" >500GB Storage</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right" >1000GB Storage</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic" >2000GB Storage</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="background-grey">
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt icons"></i>Bandwith</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">Limited</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic">Unlimited</td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-envelope icons"></i>Email</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">25 emails</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">45 emails</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic">65 emails</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="background-grey">
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="far fa-life-ring icons"></i>Support</td>
            <td colspan="3" class="basic-columns td-basic">24/7 support</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-cube icons"></i>Product</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">20 products</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">30 products</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic">60 products</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="background-grey">
            <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-users icons"></i>Users</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">1 users</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">10 users</td>
            <td class="basic-columns td-basic">15 users</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: text-align: center ?

Comment: не работает к сожалению почему-то

Comment: нее...вы наверно тегу пишите а вы напишите td

Comment: вот так например: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jOPojxy

Comment: я написал ответ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю задачу, то для `.button-columns` нужно условие `text-align: center;`

Однако, так как у вас все содержимое в таблице по центру, то лучше так:

```
table>td { text-align: center; }
```

Только таблице присвоить свой `class`.

```css
@import "reset.css";
html {
  font-size: 0.625em;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: 29px solid hsl(219, 27%, 31%);
}

.border-right {
  border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 81%);
  ;
}

.background-light {
  background: #F2F2F2;
}

.background-grey {
  background: #E3E3E3;
}

.left-column {
  width: 31.3rem;
}

.header {
  height: 15.9rem;
}

.basic-columns {
  width: 28rem;
  height: 7.2rem;
}

.button-columns {
  width: 28rem;
  height: 12rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.td-basic {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 28rem;
  height: 7.2rem;
  font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 28%);
}

.icons {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 52%);
}


/* .flex-button{
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }    */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arimo, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
  /* line-height: 2.8rem; */
  padding: 1.3rem 4.6rem 0.9rem 4.6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 0.3rem #ccc;
}

.dark-btn {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 28%);
  border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(0, 0%, 25%);
}

.green-btn {
  background-color: hsl(84, 60%, 48%);
  border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(84, 64%, 42%);
}

.red-btn {
  background-color: hsl(356, 85%, 62%);
  border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(356, 72%, 55%);
}

.blue-btn {
  background-color: hsl(178, 60%, 31%);
  border-bottom: 0.7rem solid hsl(177, 68%, 27%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arimo:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Prising Table</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <!-- <caption>Test table for PE</caption> -->
    <colgroup>
      <col span="2" class="own-items">
      <col class="another-items">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="left-column header border-right">Заголовок 1</th>
        <th class="basic-columns header border-right">Standart</th>
        <th class="basic-columns header border-right">Ultimate</th>
        <th class="basic-columns header">Premium</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class="flex-button left-column border-right button-columns"><a href="#void" class="button dark-btn">Contact Us</a></td>
        <td class="button-columns border-right"><a href="#void" class="button green-btn">Buy now</a></td>
        <td class="button-columns border-right"><a href="#void" class="button red-btn">Buy now</a></td>
        <td class="button-columns"><a href="#void" class="button blue-btn">Buy now</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="background-light">
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-archive icons"></i>Storage</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">500GB Storage</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">1000GB Storage</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic">2000GB Storage</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="background-grey">
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt icons"></i>Bandwith</td>
        <td colspan="2" class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">Limited</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic">Unlimited</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-envelope icons"></i>Email</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">25 emails</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">45 emails</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic">65 emails</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="background-grey">
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="far fa-life-ring icons"></i>Support</td>
        <td colspan="3" class="basic-columns td-basic">24/7 support</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-cube icons"></i>Product</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">20 products</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">30 products</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic">60 products</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="background-grey">
        <td class="left-column td-basic border-right"><i class="fas fa-users icons"></i>Users</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">1 users</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic border-right">10 users</td>
        <td class="basic-columns td-basic">15 users</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выровнять inline-block по центру ячейки достаточно написать для ячейки text-align: center;